# Xcode 13 translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints crashes app

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, xcode13

I have several views implemented programatically in the app without using storyboard.

```
let customView = UIView()
    actionSheetHomeCall.view.addSubview(customView)
    customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: actionSheetHomeCall.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    customView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: actionSheetHomeCall.view.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    customView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: actionSheetHomeCall.view.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    customView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 175).isActive = true
```

When running the app in Xcode 13, app crashes by giving the error`NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Must translate autoresizing mask into constraints to have _setHostsLayoutEngine:YES.'`

if I remove `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` from the code, the ui is messy. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: have you checked any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=Must%20translate%20autoresizing%20mask%20into%20constraints%20to%20have%20_setHostsLayoutEngine%3aYES)?

Comment: What is `actionSheetHomeCall`?